# Old bike: replaced rear axle but the tire goes off the axis when I get on it

Tags: road-bike, replacement, axle

I just broke and then replaced my rear axle on an old timey race bike I bought online.

Everything seems to go smoothly when the bike is up on a stand or on at my side, but once I get on it and try to pedal, the wheel immediately goes off axis and rubs against other parts

BTW it's a hollow/quick release axle, which I measured to be the exact same size as the previous one

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Some photos and/or part specs might be helpful for people wanting to answer this.

Comment: I find a similar issue with my vintage Reyolds 531 framed bike. I find the rear wheel axle does slip unless I seriously tighten the QR. So tight that I sometimes find I need to lever it open with a spanner!

Comment: @MiguelH that's often because of worn/hardened serrations on the dropout and inside face of the QR's nut.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered changing the whole wheel?  I wonder if the core of your axle may be worn or bent.

Comment: Note that the question says that the axle is new.